# Kafka Producer Failed - Unexpected error code: 87

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

Trying to sent Avro format message to Kafka and consume it. It was not sending a message until after some research added Thread.sleep(16000) in order for producer to wait on the message. However it stopped working again. It is `org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.Errors - Unexpected error code: 87. Failed to produce messages to topic`.

Any advise? My code below

```
public class AvroAutomationTest3IT {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AvroAutomationTest3IT.class);
    private static Properties producerProps;
    private final String topic = "topic.one";

    String schemaPath = "src/test/resources/automation-tests/sample-avro.avsc";

    // subject convention is "<topic-name>-value"
    String subject = topic + "-value";

    // avsc json string.
    String schema = null;

    // kafka broker list.
    private static String brokers = "xxx:9093";
    // schema registry url.
    private static String registry = "xxx:8081";

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create();

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() throws IOException {
        producerProps = new Properties();
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
        producerProps.put("acks", "1");
        producerProps.put("reconnect.backoff.ms", "5000");
        producerProps.put("retry.backoff.ms", "1000");
        producerProps.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, registry);
        //producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
        producerProps.put(KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class.getName());
        // producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
        //  producerProps.put(VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        producerProps.put(CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "AvroProducer");
        // producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "0");
        // producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "0");

        //configure the KafkaAvroSerializer
        producerProps.put(VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, "16384");
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "1");
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, "33554432");

        //consumer properties
        producerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
        producerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
        producerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
        producerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "NewConsumer");

        producerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        producerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 10);

        //sslConfig
        producerProps.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
        producerProps.put("ssl.truststore.location", "C:/Users/xx/truststore.jks");
        producerProps.put("ssl.truststore.password", "expeditors");
        producerProps.put("ssl.keystore.location", "C:/Users/xx/xx.jks");
        producerProps.put("ssl.keystore.password", "xxx");
        producerProps.put("ssl.key.password", "xxx");

    }

    @Test
         public void avroTest() throws Exception {
        sendMessage();
        Thread.sleep(16000);

        readMessage();


    }

    public void readMessage() {
        KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(producerProps);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
        try {
            ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(15000));

            // assertEquals(2, records.count(), "Expected 2 record");
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record : records) {
                try {
                    JsonElement el = this.parseAvroMessage(topic, record.value());

                    System.out.printf("offset = %d, value = %s\n", record.offset(), el);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            consumer.commitAsync();
            consumer.close(Duration.ofMillis(3000));
        }
    }

    private JsonElement parseAvroMessage(String topic, byte[] value) {
        HashMap<String, String> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put("schema.registry.url", registry);

        KafkaAvroDeserializer deserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer();
        deserializer.configure(configs, true);
        Object obj = deserializer.deserialize(topic, value);
        return gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), JsonElement.class);
    }

    public void sendMessage() throws IOException {

        // construct kafka producer.
        Producer<Integer, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<Integer, GenericRecord>(producerProps);


        // message key.
        // int userIdInt = 1;
        // message value, avro generic record.
        GenericRecord record = this.buildRecord();

        // send avro message to the topic page-view-event.
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<Integer, GenericRecord>("visibility.avro.topic.source.one", null, record));
        // producer.flush();
    }

    public GenericRecord buildRecord() throws IOException {

        // avsc json string.
        String schemaString = null;

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(schemaPath);
        try {
            schemaString = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }

        // avro schema.
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString);

        GenericRecord metadata = new GenericData.Record(schema.getField("metadata").schema());
        metadata.put("version", "1");
        metadata.put("eventName", "event.name");

        GenericRecord data = new GenericData.Record(schema.getField("data").schema());

        data.put("name", "Bob");
        data.put("age", 25);

        GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        record.put("metadata", metadata);
        record.put("data", data);

        return record;
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend to remove all non-necessary code and provide a minimal reproducable example so we have the chance to narrow down the error. Ideally, you will also clearly seperate consumer properties with producer properties and remove commented out code. Can you say which line exactly throws the error?

Comment: Note: You should not add producer and consumer configs to the same properties object. Kafka also includes MockProducer and MockConsumer, so you should not need to use real brokers or registries to test serialization and sending data

Comment: Also... Do you really need Avro **and** JSON? Why are you trying to `toString` your Avro objects?

Comment: @OneCriketeer. Just to be able to view output to confirm that consumer is pulling something before I write a real test. I don't think Mock Producer and MockConsumer will work with Avro Registery, I have to have in order to produce Avro message. At least I have not find a way to do it with Avro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I needed to un-comment  // int userIdInt = 1; and use userIdInt instead of null in this line of code:

// send avro message to the topic page-view-event.
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<Integer, GenericRecord>("visibility.avro.topic.source.one", null, record));