# Unknown KafkaError 87 from Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am writing an Avro message to Kafka using Confluent:

```py
import avro_validator
import avro.schema
from confluent_kafka import avro as confluent_avro
from confluent_kafka.cimpl import KafkaError, Message


schema = avro.schema.Parse(schema_src)
validator = avro_validator.schema.Schema(schema_file).parse()
record_schema = confluent_avro.loads(str(schema))

producer = AvroProducer(conf, default_value_schema=record_schema)

validator.validate(data)  # confirms the data matches the avro schema

producer.produce(
  topic=topic,
  value=data,
 callback=lambda err, msg: on_delivery(err, msg, data),
)
producer.poll(0)
```

My callback function is as follows:

```
def on_delivery(err: Optional[KafkaError], msg: Message, data: dict):
    if err is not None:
        logger.exception(
            f"Delivery Report: Message production failed: {err.name()} {err.code()} {err.str()}"
        )
    else:
        logger.debug(
            f"Delivery Report: Message produced successfully: {msg.value()}"
        )
```

All I get is the vague message:
`Delivery Report: Message production failed: ERR_87? 87 Err-87?`
I have no idea what error code 87 means, it does not appear to be listed in the enumerations for KafkaError.

Update: Thanks to the comments below I have determined that 87 means "[INVALID_RECORD](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_error_codes) This record has failed the validation on broker and hence will be rejected."

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Share your schema and data. Problem seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63694512/kafka-producer-failed-unexpected-error-code-87

Comment: When you see a Kafka error code, you can check https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_error_codes to find out what it means

Comment: If you would like to change your edit to an answer, you can place that below